# How to verify the input of Pretrained Network using Libtorch?

Tags: python, c++, neural-network, pre-trained-model, libtorch

How to get the Input of pretrained model(saved as .pt) using Libtorch? Does Libtorch has some method to fetch the input of function "forward"?
I am new to Libtorch and Neural Network. I will Appreciate if you can help.

following is the code of Libtorch:

```
auto method = module.get_method("forward");
    auto schema = method.function().getSchema();

    for(auto sche : schema.arguments())
    {
        std::string input_name = sche.name();
        std::cout << input_name << std::endl;
    }
```

and the output is: `self input`
I want to fetch the parameter "input", how to solve that?